# How do I make BigFloat an instance of Arbitrary (for QuickCheck)?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

The numbers package has the [`BigFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-BigFloat.html) type.

QuickCheck has the [`Arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html) typeclass.

Because `Double` is an instance of `Arbitrary`, I can already do this:

```
sample (arbitrary :: Gen Double)
```

But I can't do this because `BigFloat e` isn't an instance of `Arbitrary`:

```
sample (arbitrary :: Gen (BigFloat Prec10))
```

How do I make `BigFloat e` an instance of `Arbitrary`?

**Update**. I'd love some additional information. See the comment in the bounty.

Comment: Something like `instance Epsilon e => Arbitrary (BigFloat e) where arbitrary = fromRational <$> arbitrary` should do it.

Comment: Never depend on `Arbitrary` instances giving any particularly nice statistical distributions. They tend to be designed based on what their authors think will be most helpful for testing, rather than any theoretical considerations.

Comment: Also, orphan instances are kind of evil, so it's usually best to make an instance for a newtype instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer from the comments as a community-wiki answer:

Something like:

```
instance Epsilon e => Arbitrary (BigFloat e) where arbitrary = fromRational <$> arbitrary
```